# A Partial Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ evaluated at $\varepsilon=0$ for

$F=\|\vec{\dot{y^\varepsilon}}\|^2$ 
where $$\vec{y^\varepsilon}=\frac{\vec{y(x)}-\varepsilon \vec{\eta(x)}}{\|\vec{y(x)}-\varepsilon \vec{\eta(x)}\|}$$ and $\vec{\eta(x)}$ is smooth?

Thanks!

Comment: How might one solve this?